# Find all records from today to next or last 30 days

Tags: php, datetime, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm on ZendFramework2 and using doctrine2.

I want to find all records from today's DateTime to next or last 30 days related to deal.

Here's my doctrine query and code,

```
$emailRepo = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Email')->findBy(['deal' => $deal]);
foreach ($emailRepo as $email) {
            $sendAt = $email->getSendAt();
        }
```

I have **DateTime** object in sendAt variable,

From some references I found this **strtotime** function.

```
$data = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("+30 days"));
$data = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("-30 days"));
```

But It didn't worked for me.

What is the proper way to write it?

Comment: `echo $sendAt->modify("+30 days")->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');`

Comment: Thanks for comment, I want to find the records between two dates. I think this will probably give me only date of 30days from database's date. @splash58.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching little bit, **Query builder** worked for me.

**For Next 30 days,**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("+30 days"))

$sendAt = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Email')
            ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e')
            ->where('e.sendAt BETWEEN :today AND :n30days')
            ->setParameter('today', date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('n30days', $date)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```

**For Last 30 days,**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("-30 days"))

$sendAt = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\Email')
            ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e')
            ->where('e.sendAt BETWEEN :n30days AND :today')
            ->setParameter('today', date('Y-m-d h:i:s'))
            ->setParameter('n30days', $date)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();
```